# Android SimpleAdapter - Asking to change type of List<Map>

Tags: java, android, list, dictionary, simpleadapter

I am implementing a `SimpleAdapter` like this:

```
    List<Map> data = getDrawerData();
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data,R.layout.drawer_list_item,new String[] {"drawer_icon","drawer_text"},new int[] {R.id.drawer_icon, R.id.drawer_text});
```

However, 2nd line gives me this error:

> The constructor SimpleAdapter(MainActivity, List, int, String[], int[]) is undefined

`Two fixes`

`1. Cast argument 'data' to 'List<? extends Map<String, ?>>'` or
`2. Change type of 'data' to 'List<? extends Map<String, ?>>'`

I Chose the `Cast` option, but this then only showed the icons for the drawer list items, not their `TextView` labels...

I followed this tutorial: http://shenhengbin.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/listview-simpleadapter/

Comment: create custom adapter by extendng ArrayAdapter

Comment: did u import the `SimpleAdapter`...`import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;`

Comment: `@Biraj` Is there no way I can use `SimpleAdapter`?

Comment: `@bakriOnFire` yes I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resorted to using a Custom Adapter as per [this](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429) example. I ran into an error ("Variable must provide either dimension expressions or an array") with this bit in that link:

```
    Weather weather_data[] = new Weather[] // << HERE
    {
        new Weather(R.drawable.weather_cloudy, "Cloudy"),
        new Weather(R.drawable.weather_showers, "Showers"),
        new Weather(R.drawable.weather_snow, "Snow"),
        new Weather(R.drawable.weather_storm, "Storm"),
        new Weather(R.drawable.weather_sunny, "Sunny")
    };
```

I changed this to `Weather weather_data[] = new Weather[NUM_OF_ITEMS]` to fix it :)
Hope this helps someone.